# Getting an error for the below IAM policy "This policy contains the following error: Missing required field Effect "

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

````
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Sid": "Stmt1493724986000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateExportTask",
                "logs:DescribeExportTasks",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:<region>:logs:*:<account number>:log-group:<loggroupname>*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1493724996000",
            "Statement": [{
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                    "ec2:DescribeImages",
                    "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                    "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                    "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                    "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
                    "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                    "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                    "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
                    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                    "iam:ListPolicies",
                    "iam:GetPolicy",
                    "iam:GetPolicyVersion"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1493725007000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:<region>:s3:::<bucketname>"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1493725032000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:<region>:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1493724986000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateExportTask",
        "logs:DescribeExportTasks",
        "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
        "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
        "logs:GetLogEvents",
        "logs:FilterLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn::logs:::log-group:"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1493724996000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeImages",
        "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
        "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
        "ec2:DescribeRouteTables",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
        "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
        "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "iam:ListPolicies",
        "iam:GetPolicy",
        "iam:GetPolicyVersion"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn::s3:::/"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1493725007000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn::s3:::/"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1493725032000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn::s3:::/"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

1. You still had `"Statement": [` in the second statement. That does not belong there.
2. Define the right ARNs in your Resource sections.